# SQL: Get an article for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables article and category.

```
  nid | title | status
---+-------------+-------
 1 |           abc |     1
 2 |           ggg |      1
 3 |           kkk |      0
 4 |          rrr |      1
 5 |           fff |      1
 6 |           ggg |      1
```

Where status = 1 is published.

```
cid | nid 
---+-------------
 1 |           1 
 2 |           2 
 2 |            3 
 3 |           4 
 1 |           5 
 2 |           6
```

Now I want to get a one nid for each cid, no double occurrence of cid where status is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select c.cid, max(c.nid)
from category c join
     article a
     on c.nid = a.nid
where a.status = 1
group by c.cid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT t2.cid, MAX(t2.nid)
FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.nid = t1.nid and t1.status = 1
GROUP BY t2.cid;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must decide which nid to show for a cid in case of multiple matches. Let's say you want the maximum nid. Select from category and look up articles for their status. Then aggregate.

```
select cid, max(nid)
from category
where nid in (select nid from article where status = 1)
group by cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cid 
FROM category       AS a1
INNER JOIN article  AS a2 ON a1.nid = a2.nid
WHERE a1.[STATUS] = 1
```